# Adding a custom control to the designer

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I have a custom class (CustomTabControl), derived from the System.Windows.Forms.TabControl, that I would like to modify at design time.

I have also the necessity to pass a reference to another control when creating the object of type CustomTabControl.

**How I did it:**

I create at design time a normal TabControl and then to modified the type of the reference and the object to CustomTabControl. This was working until I had the necessity to pass a reference (to another control in the form) in the constructor of the CustomTabControl.

It's seems that I cannot pass a parameter to the constructor at design level.

Initially I have:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl1;
tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();

/*Then I change manually the type of the reference 
and of the object and this works:*/

private CustomTabControl tabControl1;
tabControl1 = CustomTabControl();

/*But If I want to pass a reference to another form's control, 
visual studio continue to removes me the creation of the object:*/

private CustomTabControl tabControl1;
tabControl1 = CustomTabControl(this.anotherFormsControl);

/*after a while the creation is removed, 
but the previous modifications of the tabControl1 still remain on the designer.cs, 
and this gives me of course an error: 
"no variable tabControl1 has been declared".
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Forms doesn't support controls without default constructor to be added to other control without proper designer class decoration to the control.
To make think easer, remove the constructor with parameter and declare a property to set the control: this.anotherFormsControl to tab.

Comment: Thanks, I had already thought about that possibility, but I wanted that the internal reference to anotherFormsComponent is inialized in the constructor of tabControl1 ;)